# How to add a setTimeout() to a query selector

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.stylebutton').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  })
});
</script>
```

I want to wait 10 seconds before running. I have tried

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.stylebutton').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', setTimeout(function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  }),10000)
});
</script>
```

But I get a console error of `can not define this`

Comment: try inside a function like ()=>setTiimeout ....

Comment: You want to wait 10 seconds before running the code that attaches the event listeners or you want to wait 10 seconds before running the code of each event listener after a click happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be invoked inside the callback.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.stylebutton').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setTimeout(()=>this.style.backgroundColor = 'black', 10000);
  })
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know the it had to be outside the callback

Comment: @hedgethenight Glad to help.